# select value based on other columns

Tags: sql

I am quite stuck here. I have this table:

```
  Name  |  Value   |  Date    
------------------------------   
  A     |  Active  | 2020-08-07    
  A     | Inactive | 2020-08-06    
  A     |  Active  | 2020-08-05   
  B     | Inactive | 2020-08-06    
  B     |  Active  | 2020-08-01    
  C     |  Active  | 2020-08-02
```

And I want to select only the latest records for each name  (based on date)

```
  Name  |  Value   |  Date    
------------------------------    
  A     |  Active  | 2020-08-07    
  B     | Inactive | 2020-08-06    
  C     |  Active  | 2020-08-02
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet?

Comment: Yeap, but I it seems that I made it super complex for no reason, that's why I summarized a simplified version of what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

With an index on `(name, date)`, this often has really good performance.

Another method that works well on many databases is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck with over partition by and I couldn't think of that...

Comment: Actually the 2nd method is exactly what I needed to in my query. Thanks a lot.